# Where to write parameters to create order programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.3

I want to create order programmatically in Magento 2:
 I have followed this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html

> Now, My questions are:
>    1. Where I will put the temp order code.At  which path  in my custom module ?
>    2. And how I will run the function to create the order programmatically?

Comment: my topic is same but my question is different

Comment: you can refer here, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2/